# SBT assembly: not a valid command assembly

Tags: java, sbt, sbt-assembly

I want to make one jar file from [XSL Transform](https://github.com/joepjoosten/XSL-Tester) project. If am not wrong to do this I need [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.

So based on the readme I created and added to:

```
@ubuntu:~/scripts/XSL-tester$cat /project/assembly.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

after that I tried to run sbt assembly:

```
    @ubuntu:~/scripts/XSL-tester$ sbt assembly
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/x/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/home/x/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.11.2/jars/sbt-assembly.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.11.2!sbt-assembly.jar (2101ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /home/x/scripts/XSL-tester/project
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/home/x/scripts/XSL-tester/)
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]
```

Others says that it needs to be added to:

```
@ubuntu:~/scripts/XSL-tester$ cat /home/x/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt 
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

too...but it not helped.

sbt version:

```
@ubuntu:~/scripts/XSL-tester$ sbt sbtVersion
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/x/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/x/scripts/XSL-tester/project
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/home/x/scripts/XSL-tester/)
[info] 0.13.0
```